# Request parameter is visible in url on a GET form request

Tags: asp.net-mvc

On my controller I have this action:

```
[HttpGet]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Add()
{
    // get data and put in viewModel

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

When I click on my Add button - next to the dropdown where title "MyDefaultAddress" is selected - to retrieve data to pre-fill certain data in the formular then url changes to:

```
/Addresses/Add?title=MyDefaultAddress
```

The add view which is returned to the client includes with HTML.Partial("Index") in the Add view the index view, because the index view has a dropdown for the title with a delete/add/edit button.

How can I prevent that any parameter is visible in the url on a GET request when I actually do not send any params explicitly?

Thats the way I do the request:

```
 $(".add-edit-btn").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest("form")
            .attr({ 'action': '/@MVC.Configuration.Name/@MVC.Configuration.Addresses.Name/' + $(this).val(), 'method': 'Get' })
            .submit();

        });
```

With $(this).val() I get the value "Add" which is the value attribute from the add button. Do I have to check my form with jquery and remove the title before I do the add request?

When I am inside the HttpGet Add() action and do this:

```
Request.QueryString
{title=AtHOme}
    [System.Web.HttpValueCollection]: {title=Zuhause}
    base: {title=Zuhause}
    AllKeys: {string[1]}
```

Comment: Practically by definition, submitting a form via GET means "pass the input values in the query string". If you don't want that to happen, don't use GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by default, GET method of HTTP is designed to show parameters in URL. The only alternative is to use POST method.

Comment: But I alreay have an action with name Add() which is the HttpPost.